# Kafka Embedded with Spark. Dependencies problems

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to use Spark Streaming 2.0.0 with Kafka 0.10. I'm using to my integration test https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka but I have some problems starting the server. When I tried with Spark 2.2.0 it works.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>net.manub</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${embedded-kafka.version}</version> -->I tried many versions.
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

An exception or error caused a run to abort: kafka.server.KafkaServer$.$lessinit$greater$default$2()Lorg/apache/kafka/common/utils/Time; 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.server.KafkaServer$.$lessinit$greater$default$2()Lorg/apache/kafka/common/utils/Time;
    at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$class.startKafka(EmbeddedKafka.scala:467)
    at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafka$.startKafka(EmbeddedKafka.scala:38)
    at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafka$.start(EmbeddedKafka.scala:55)
    at iris.orange.ScalaTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaTest.scala:10)
```

It seems an problem about dependencies but I didnt' get to work. I chose a embedded kafka which uses the same kafka version.

Comment: you need to get the spark version specific version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the proper version of the `spark-streaming-kafka`
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10/2.0.0

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```